# how can I re-call this function? not experienced with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't know how to call counter() a second time after it runs on page load

I made a new "instance" of the counter, I think. And this does work but there must be a correct way. I need to call it in replay()

```
/**
 * @fileoverview demo 
 */

class ReVideo {
    constructor() {
        this.time = 5;
...
        this.timer = document.getElementById("update");
        this.counter = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);
        this.fader = fader();
        this.counter2 = "";
...

        this.retry.addEventListener('click', () => this.replay());
...
    }

    countdown() {
        this.time--;
        if (this.time > -1) {
            this.timer.innerHTML = "seconds remaining: " + this.time;
        } else {
            this.timer.innerHTML = "You Lose!";
            this.watch.style.display = "block";
            this.retry.style.display = "block";
            clearInterval(this.counter);
            clearInterval(this.counter2);
            this.coins++;
            this.coinCount.innerHTML = "Coins: " + this.coins;
        }
        this.notice.style.visibility = "visible";
        this.notice.innerHTML = "Loaded";
    }

...

    replay() {
        this.time = 5;
        this.watch.style.display = "none";
        this.notice.style.visibility = "hidden";
        fader("Loaded");
        this.retry.style.display = "none";
        this.counter2 = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);
        this.counter2;
    }
...

}
new ReVideo();
```

It does not run if i say counter();

Comment: `It does not run if i say counter();` because counter is not a function

Comment: Or is it better to just move the whole counter to a web worker? will that help?

Comment: A few things about your code: `setInterval` returns a number, so it's unclear why you initialize `this.counter2 = "";` You also have `this.counter2;` at the end of `replay`, which does nothing. I don't see any reason to have `counter2` in any case; just use `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a helper `counter` function to return the `intervalID` like:

```
counter () {
  const interval = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);
  return interval;
}
```

and in your constructor, you could assign the `intervalID` to some variable like:

```
this.interval = counter();
```

Then you can stop the counter by passing the variable holding the `intervalID` like `clearInterval(this.interval);`